# How to detect ndash entity embedded in a textarea using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, entity

I have a textarea within an HTML page into which my users paste content.

There is often an "–" (`&ndash;`)(\x2013) embedded in that content.  I need to detect and replace it and store it in a database as `&ndash;`.

My code `document.getElementById("input").value.replace("-", "&ndash;");` only detects the "-" (minus sign)(\x2D).

What would be the proper parameter to detect the ndash?

Comment: What's the encoding of the page where this resides?

Comment: The page from which the content was pasted is UTF-8.  I did not specify the encoding on my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use its Unicode code point in a pattern literal

```
document.getElementById("input").value.replace( /\u2013/g, "&ndash;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
document.getElementById("input").value.replace(String.fromCharCode(150), "&ndash;");
```

Comment: Why 150?  The numeric for ndash is 8211?

Comment: I tried it... It eliminates the ndash rather than substituting the entity.  Curious.